# Can we use single database connection to execute multiple database select statements simultaneously from multiple threads?

Tags: sql-server, database, multithreading

I want to use single database connection from multiple threads to read (or to execute only select statements) in MS SQL Server in simultaneously. Is it possible to execute all these select statements in simultaneously from different threads.

I m using MS SQL Server from C++ in Linux environment. I need to create Database connection pools for reading and writing separately. So i want to know is there a possibility of sharing a same connection between threads to read only.

The select statements may return multiple rows (more than one row or result set). Will this be a problem?

Answer (score 4):

Yes there will be a problem. Only one command can be executed at a time.
But you'll be fine using multiple connections, connection pooling works great for SQL server.

Comment: Indeed.  Feel free to create a new connection whenever it is needed.  Let .Net manage available connections for you.  Connection pooling is a great thing.

Comment: I m using MS SQL Server from C++ in Linux environment. I need to create Database connection pools for reading and writing separately. So i want to know is there a possibility of sharing a same connection between threads to read only.

Answer (score 4):

Don't use the same connection across threads.  Only one command can be executed per connection.  Create a connection for each thread.  I'd suggest making a helper class to make this easier for you.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to use single database connection from multiple threads to read (or to execute only select 
>   statements) in MS SQL Server in simultaneously

You should start reading the documentation and not start having funny ideas that whas you want matters here.

Yes, you CAN do that (MARS is the topic-  read it up) but one connection can alwayso nly have one transaction context so it isa  good approach to ahvem ultiple selects in one transaction (insert, couple of upserts etc.) but bad as a generic approach for progrmaming database connections.

Follow the recipes which mean iopen a conenction when you need it, close it when done and dont be afraid to run mtultiple connections.

Answer (score 0):

If you worry about multi process in SQL Server, must think of two option.

1. Parallelism settings
2. AlwaysOn setup

The first one helps you by executing a single query with more than one cpu logical core; while the second one helps you to have a load balance, when you have concurrent connections.