# What happens when we click on SSMS 'New Query' button?

Tags: sql-server-2012, ssms

When we click on the 'New Query' Button on Sql Server Management Studio does it creates a new connection?
if not how can i create multiple connection using my local SSMS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, `New Query` creates a new connection to the database. Each query window maintains an independent connection.

The connection number is the number shown in `()` brackets at both the end of the tab name and in the status bar (after the user name)

[image]

Shown circled in red - this query window has connection number 57 to it's respective server. An `sp_who2` executed in this window will show that connection 57 is active and running `sp_who2`.

Comment: Thanks, Is there any way we can know currently how many connections to the server is opened?

Comment: @DeepakKumarPadhy - sp_who2 gives you information about all open connections to the server - if you have sufficient permissions. If you don't, then it only shows you information about your own connection.

Answer (score 0):

When you click on new query, it will open an editor on which you can try writing your queries.

When you click on new query, you need to make sure that appropriate database has been selected. By default, it will  be pointing to Temp.

A new connection will not be opened rather it points to one of the data bases on the server

Hope it helps..

Comment: Actually, if you already have a query window open when you create a new one, a new connection is created to the same server. If you have no query windows open by the time you click, you will be prompted to create a new connection.

Comment: @Dan: Suppose i have one query window opened and after that when i click on 'New Query' button does it creates 2 connection or only 1?
and if 1 connection how can i create multiple connection on my local system using SSMS?

Comment: @Deepak It uses the existing opened connection.If it time outs then it will prompt to create another connection

Comment: @Avinash: How can i create multiple connection in my local system using SSMS?

Comment: @Deepak..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8343199/can-we-use-single-database-connection-to-execute-multiple-database-select-statem..This might help you..

Comment: @Avinash: That is not true. Each query window has its own connection, that can be disconnected, reconnected or changed to point to another server. Why else would there be a "Disconnect all queries"-option in the Query > Connection menu? Also, try opening SSMS and create two new queries that point to the same database. Execute a WAITFOR DELAY '00:10' statement in both of them, then create a third window where you query sys.processes. As you will see, there will be a connection for each of your windows.